# how to decrypt a password in centos-71

Tags: centos7, chef

I have installed Oracle VM and on top of it Centos-71. I am logging into the centos by vigrant user and the password is also set during configuring it with chef. Is there a way to decrypt the password of root ?

Answer (score 5):

In short: no.

Passwords in linux are not encrypted, but rather salted and hashed using a one-way hash algorithm. It is not possible to derive the cleartext password from the hash. It *is* possible to brute-force this, but doing so could take anywhere from years to centuries.

Comment: I think that passwords in Linux have been hashed since the very first implementation.

Comment: @kasperd I believe you're right. I was just trying to sort through this in my head, and was coming to the same conclusion. I've fixed the answer.